# How to implement dropdownbutton into a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

Im working on a company project. But I can't simply get the idea of how to implement a basic dropdown button into a function but I can't seem to make the values change in the dropdown function what do you think im doing wrong here's my code:

```
Widget buildDropdownField({
  required String dropdownHeader,
  required String dropdownValue,
}) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(dropdownHeader),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      //dropdownField
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        elevation: 16,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
        underline: Container(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        ),
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue!;
          });
        },
        items: <String>['-', 'Geçti', 'Kaldı', 'Belirsiz']
            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap with StatefulBuilder it will work.

```
Widget buildDropdownField(
      {required String dropdownHeader, required String dropdownValue}) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(dropdownHeader),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (_, setDropState) {
            return DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              elevation: 16,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setDropState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue!;
                });
              },
              items: <String>['-', 'Geçti', 'Kaldı', 'Belirsiz']
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. use **StatefulBuilder** Refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

Your dropdown function:

```
buildDropdownField({
  required String dropdownHeader,
  required String dropdownValue,
}) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(dropdownHeader),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      //dropdownField
      StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['-', 'Geçti', 'Kaldı', 'Belirsiz']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      })
    ],
  );
}
```

Your Widget:

```
buildDropdownField(
      dropdownHeader: 'dropdownHeader',
      dropdownValue: '-',
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Result after selection->[image]

Comment: It does work but its state resets once I get to the next screen using a stepper widget I want to be able to store the value I choose let it stay like that once its chosen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't update the parameter with the new value. It did update the parameter, but the function will still getting the value from it's calling.

I did not know the `buildDropdownField` function is inside a class or not, but it's okay and I will provide the solutions for both scenarios.

**Within the Class**

You need to create a variable within a class outside the functions.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _dropDownValue = '-';

  Widget buildDropdownField({required String dropdownHeader}) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(dropdownHeader),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        //dropdownField
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: _dropDownValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _dropDownValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['-', 'Geçti', 'Kaldı', 
  'Belirsiz'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Outside the Class**

You need to turn it into Stateful Widget in order for the drop down text to change. Once the dropdown is a stateful widget, you can use the solution above or a callback to make the changes on parent class.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _dropDownValue = '-';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DropDownWidget(
          dropdownHeader: 'Name',
          dropdownValue: _dropDownValue,
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _dropDownValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String dropdownHeader;
  final String dropdownValue;
  final Function(String?)? onChanged;

  DropDownWidget({required this.dropdownHeader, required this.dropdownValue, this.onChanged, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownWidgetState createState() => _DropDownWidgetState();
}

class _DropDownWidgetState extends State<DropDownWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(widget.dropdownHeader),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        //dropdownField
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: widget.dropdownValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
          elevation: 16,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
          underline: Container(
            height: 2,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ),
          onChanged: widget.onChanged,
          items: <String>['-', 'Geçti', 'Kaldı', 'Belirsiz'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Talking for the situation that is inside the class: I want that dropdownvalue to be given as a parameter. How can I achieve that

Comment: For that case, you need a callback parameter (onChanged) that update the value provided to the dropdownValue parameter. You can refer the 'Outside the class' solution to implement the callback, it's similar to that.