# setState not working from inside AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call setState inside an AlertDialog, but surprisingly setState is not changing the state variable. The variable (tasbeehChantCanAdd) i want to set from the dialog box is inside the body of the main page(outside the dialog box) This is the code for the alertDialog:

```
    Future<void> _alertRemoveEntry(BuildContext context, String textToRemove) {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: (){},
            child: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(15.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: const Text('Enter your info',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,fontSize: 14),),
                  content:  Container(
                      height: 150,
                      child: const Text("Sure to remove this?")
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                              ),
                              primary: Colors.purple,
                            ),
                            child: Text("CANCEL"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),

                          Container(
                            width: 20,
                          ),

                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                //side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)
                              ),
                              primary: Colors.purple,
                            ),

                            child: Text("REMOVE"),
                            onPressed: (){
                              setState((){
                                tasbeehChantCanAdd = "state changed";
                              });
                              ClassHub().myListSharePreference("sptasbeehAddedList", "set", tasbeehChantCanAdd, "");
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();

                            },
                          ),
                        ],),),

                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Please what am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main state class also have `setState` and while you are using `StatefulBuilder` it also has `setState`, being scope priority `setState`  is coming from `StatefulBuilder`. You can rename it and use

```dart
   child: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setStateSB) {
       ....
             setState((){ /// for state class IU update
                  tasbeehChantCanAdd = "state changed";
                  });
               setStateSB((){ // update Ui inside dialog
                   tasbeehChantCanAdd = "state changed";
                   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your AlertDialog widget inside **`StatefulBuilder`** hope its helpful to you.

Refer `StatefulBuilder` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

```
yourDropdown(BuildContext context) {
 return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, StateSetter setState) {
              return AlertDialog(
                 
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70782259/13997210)

Answer (score 0):

Are you me from another dimension? Seriously, I just solved the same problem. I don't know if it is the recommended way of setting states on dialog, since the documentation on `showDialog` mentions something about states, but I solved it this way:

```
var choice = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          var list = [];
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              [...]
            );
          });
        });
```

Just put the variables you need to update through `setState` just before the `StatefulBuilder`